# Bezier Curve Arc-Length Parameterization

Tags: c#, bezier

I'm learning about Bezier curves and would like to parameterize the equations for distance using an estimation method. So far, my code seems to work for single points (EG `Bezier(start=0, mid=1, end=5, nPoints=6)` yields `[0 1 2 3 4 5]`). However, when I attempt to apply this to multi-dimensional curves, my results are not as expected.

C# code (executed in Unity for visualization). The function (should) get a point on the curve (defined by the points `pts`) at a length `l`% of the length.

```
Vector3 BezierL(Vector3[] pts, float l)
{
    int i;
    float[] tVals = new float[n];
    Vector3[] points = new Vector3[n];
    float[] cumDist = new float[n];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        tVals[i] = i / (float)(n - 1);
        points[i] = Bezier(pts, tVals[i]);
        cumDist[i] = cumDist[i - 1] + 
            (points[i] - points[i - 1]).magnitude;
    }
    // Interpolate to estimate t
    float targetLen = l * cumDist[n - 1];
    int ind = Array.BinarySearch(cumDist, targetLen);
    if (ind < 0)
        ind = ~ind;
    float t = Mathf.Lerp(tVals[ind - 1], tVals[ind],
        (targetLen - cumDist[ind - 1]) / (cumDist[ind] - cumDist[ind - 1]));
    return Bezier(pts, t);
}
```

where `Bezier(Vector3[] pts, t)` gets a point on the curve defined by `pts` at time `t`. For whatever reason, this partially works in that all points are equally spaced, but some points are stacked at the initial point rather than being distributed along the curve.

[This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5373/moving-ships-between-two-planets-along-a-bezier-missing-some-equations-for-acce/5427#5427) was my reference for developing this algorithm, so I'm unsure if my implementation is incorrect, or if it only applies to lower-dimensional curves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that the points[0] is never computed.

Answer (score 0):

Oof how embarrassing, I just forgot to compute the 0th point!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Especially given what the solution was, this was basically a non-question that was solved by "an extra pair of eyes" rather than a genuine programming problem, and it kind of has its own dedicated closing option. It's probably worth deleting this question again.